# VBA to calculate a specific selection in a table (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA that will set the calculation of a specific column/range of columns to manual, within a table that is set to calculate automatically.

Because the dashboard is already so slow I do not want these specific columns/range to calculate automatically like the rest of the table. 
I'm using this vba but my whole table is still calculating automatically when I first load my cust # into my excel dashboard.

```
Sub Recalc()
Selection.Calculate
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Selection.Calculate` recalculates the selection, it does not turn off the calculations for that selection.  One can only turn off the calculations for the entire application and not specific ranges.

Comment: That answers my question, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly turn calculations on or off to a specific section, it has to apply to the application. Your best bet would be to turn all calculations off for the application, but then set a change macro to recalculate when changeshappen with a specific range. This would need to be written in the appropriate SHEET section of a your VBA editor, not MODULE

Example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:Z100")) Is Nothing Then
Range("B3:Z100").Calculate
End If

End Sub
```